# Simulation of typical cell in Poisson Voronoi tessellation

Tags: simulation, tessellations

I would like to simulate a typical cell in Poisson-Voronoi tessellation model. I want to save the Cartesian coordinates of all vertices of the typical cell for each realization. How to do it? Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Look in this [link](http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/130516-How-To-Create-Voronoi-Diagram-With-Maple), especially pay attention to the great code by David Clark.